# In distributed Database the data are distributed or the relational entities are distributed?

Tags: database, distributed-database

Distributed Database System Data are logically interrelated but i want know is that, the table's Entities are distributed or the Data of a particular tables are distributed?
Like if there is a table called User then the user's whole data will distribute. like some user's info in this Database and others in the other DB.
or the Entities like id, name, account. and all like foreign key. 
the data will be distributed by Row, and would it distribute data by table? like A database may have more tables so the tables are also distributed?

Comment: A distributed database would imply that the rows in a single table are distributed.  It wouldn't be very scalable if you had to add new entities when you added new processing power/storage.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff ,so the data will be distributed by Row, and would it distribute data by table? like A database may have more tables so the tables are also distributed?

Comment: . . The purpose is to support large tables.  Proliferation of tables is not recommended.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks